# include php not working for my navbar.php

Tags: php, html, include

I was asked to do some editing on a site and one of the things I did was use `<?php include "navbar.php" ?>` "navbar.php" was a file I created with their navigation bar. it worked seamlessly when I copied their navigation bar over to the .php file and replaced it on every page with the include.

Now I try to play with making my own website and create a navbar.php and use an include but i cannot figure out why it will not work. been to wschools.com and around on stack overflow and no solutions I have been able to try have worked. 
Here is navbar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> hello </p>`
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the page I am trying to make.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "RRstyle.css" />`
<h1> R&R Manufacturing </h1>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<?php include '/RRnavbar.php';?>
<br />
<p> This is more of the body </p>
<br />
<p> I needed more text </p>
<br />
<p> is this enough? </p>
</div>
<body>
```

I have been pouring over this for hours and cannot figure to get it to display anything from my navigation bar.

Comment: If you're running the web server on Linux, then it will be case-sensitive. Meaning `RRnavbar.php` will be different to `rrnavbar.php`.

Answer (score 0):

First, adding the "/" before a directory makes it go back to the original / directory. So that may be an issue. That's the only thing I can see. 
eg: A file in /test/ named test.html

include 'test.php' would look for /test/test.php

include '/test.php' would look for /test.php

Mind adding what exactly isn't working?

Comment: I guess I was not quite clear. It does not display anything in the RRnavbar.php file. If I copy the code onto the main page (instead of useing an include) then it worked exactly how I wanted it to. I trimmed it down from a slightly styled navigation menu to just "hello" but I still cannot get RRnavbar.php to display on the main page. (I tried removing the "/" to no avail.)

Comment: Is your index file .html or .php?

Answer (score 0):

I would add brackets to this line

```
<?php include '/RRnavbar.php';?>
```

So it reads

```
<?php include('/RRnavbar.php');?>
```